# Can I travel to Canada as a tourist with an Australian UN Convention Travel Document for refugees?

Tags: canada

Can I travel to Canada as a tourist with an Australian UN Convention Travel Document for refugees? I have an Australian Travel document or convention travel document for refugees and i want to visit Canada as a tourist

Answer (score 1):

You can but you'll [need to apply for a visitor visa first](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1180&top=16). When you are looking for flights you will also need to check for transit visa requirements at stopover airports.